# Force ViewController light mode but keep WKWebView mode adaptable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview, ios-darkmode

I'm using the newest version of Xcode for my iOS app.

I'm stuck with one small task since hours:

I want to force my View Controller to always stay in light mode, also if device is in dark mode. I'm using this code:

```
overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

This is working very well.

But there's a WKWebView in the View Controller. I want this WKWebView to stay adaptable to the color mode, so I can check via CSS if the device is in light mode or dark mode.

I tried so much but nothing worked.

Is it even possible? How?

Comment: Have you already found any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing `UIInterfaceStyle` just right before invoking `WKWebView` and setting it back before `WKWebView` dismisses. You can use `WKNavigationDelegate` for detecting `WKWebView` dismissal.